# how to align differents tables extracts from database in a row

Tags: php, css, layout

Im trying to align some differents objects in my page, but something happens and then improper. The web is the next, i dont want to give advertising is just to give you and idea:

http://gocomunio.com/?journey=33

the code is the next:

```
$v = 1;
$s = 1;
while( $equipo = mysql_fetch_assoc( $sele_equipo ) )
{
    $sele_datjornada = "select * from jornada where jornada='$jornada' AND nom_equipo='{$equipo['nombre']}'";
    $sele_datjornada = mysql_query( $sele_datjornada , $link );
    $totEmp = mysql_num_rows( $sele_datjornada );

    if( $totEmp > 0 )
    {
        switch( $v )
        {
            case 1:
                echo "<TABLE CLASS='puntos_izquierda'>";
                break;
            case 2: 
                echo "<TABLE CLASS='puntos_derecha'>";
                break;
            case 3:
                echo "<TABLE CLASS='puntos_centro'>";
                $v = 0;
                break;
            }
$v++;
```

im aligning them at right, left and center, then there is 3 cases and a counter whos raising. here is css code:

```
.puntos_izquierda tr:nth-child(odd){
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #30601e;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.puntos_derecha tr:nth-child(odd){
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #30601e;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.puntos_centro tr:nth-child(odd){
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #30601e;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

i need a way to align them all up without errors, im also trying to make margin-top but when i try the tables going disordered.

i appreciate your help, thanks forwarded.

Comment: you should do your mysql interactions using the improved mysql functions which is mysqli, also maybe to have fewer lines of code you could style all the table rows together like so:

Comment: .puntos_izquierda tr:nth-child(odd), .puntos_derecha tr:nth-child(odd), .puntos_centro tr:nth-child(odd){ width: 100%;
    background-color: #30601e;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
}